# Angular Velocity through integration

Tags: integration

How to integrate $a\ddot\theta = \frac{gsin2\theta}{2} $ to find $r\dot\theta^2$

r is the radius. I am not sure how to integrate the equation with respect to t. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

Start with

$$\ddot\theta = \frac g {2a} \sin(2\theta)$$

and multiply both sides by $\dot\theta$.  Then, we have

$$(\dot\theta)(\ddot\theta) = \frac{g}{2a} (\dot\theta)(\sin(2\theta))$$

Now, from the chain rule,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d(\dot \theta )^2}{dt}&= \frac{d(\dot \theta )^2}{d \dot \theta}  \frac{d\dot \theta }{dt}\\\\
&=2 \dot \theta \ddot \theta 
\end{align}$$

Thus, we see that the left-hand side is

$$(\dot\theta)(\ddot\theta) =\frac12 \frac{d(\dot\theta)^2}{dt}$$

Then, integrating both sides of the equation with respect to $t$ reveals

$$\frac12\int  \frac{d(\dot\theta)^2}{dt} dt=\frac{g}{2a}\int \sin(2 \theta) (\dot\theta) dt$$

or

$$\frac12 (\dot\theta)^2=-\frac{g}{4a}\cos (2\theta)+C$$

Comment: how did you use the chain rule. could you please elaborate. thank you

Comment: Sure.  I added in the answer.  Let me know how else I can improve the answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.